# Avoid Page REfresh Problem using Extjs 3.2

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, extjs

I am working on extjs based application , i need control the page refresh when user press f5 multiple times, i am getting script error when user done this.

I need to solve this issue by sending 2nd refresh request after 1st refresh one is completed.

Is there any way to achieve the above solution using extjs..

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would try to fix your error rather than trying to prevent the F5 key.  Your app should still work regardless of being refreshed multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible through asynchronous method calls, you will have to know when the users press F5 and then intercept the even then use a custom function to refresh the page. Extjs has this inbuilt http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/output/Function.html.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe (to my knowledge) there's any way to prevent a refresh.